# Servicebus python sdk keep throwing "Message lock expired"

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have an issue with the serviceBus. I have a lot of messages that are published to the service bus which is processed by the consumers behind a scaleset. What I have seen is my process just freeze after someetime with the last message in the logs that I see is
t):

```
 File "/home/ubuntu/tvsm-eventhub-consumer/consumers/serviceBusConsumer.py", line 96, in process_msg
    msg.complete()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/servicebus/common/message.py", line 325, in complete
    self._is_live('complete')
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/servicebus/common/message.py", line 97, in _is_live
    raise MessageLockExpired(inner_exception=self.auto_renew_error)
azure.servicebus.common.errors.MessageLockExpired: Message lock expired
```

I am using a 2gb single CPU machine behind a scale set in Azure. When I look at the process it takes 100% cpu util, but is in freeze mode.

My python packages version are

```
azure-servicebus==0.50.2
uamqp==1.2.5
```

This is the code I use

```
with self.queue_client.get_receiver() as queue_receiver:
 lock_time = 300
 lock_renewal = AutoLockRenew(max_workers=4)
 message = queue_receiver.fetch_next()

 msg = message[0]
 lock_renewal.register(msg, timeout=lock_time)

 proccess msg

 msg.complete()
```

5 minutes is what is set as a lock period in servicebus. Sometimes it takes more time to process my message. What could be the issue.

One more observation I see is this error

```
"2020-02-18 04:32:29,245 - ThreadPoolExecutor-0_2 -connection - work - uamqp.c_uamqp - INFO - CBS error occured on connection b'SBReceiver-e2a26b20-7d9b-47b9-bb70-da836bbcc74a'.
2020-02-18 04:32:29,246 - ThreadPoolExecutor-0_2 -receiver - _detach_received - uamqp.receiver - INFO - Received Link detach event: b'amqp:connection:forced'
Link: b'receiver-link-05cabf7d-fd64-4f65-86c0-d5ce4c67b733'
Description: b"The connection was inactive for more than the allowed 240000 milliseconds and is closed by container '2a83654461174e5492f21ff69047ec8d_G15'."
Details: None
Retryable: True
Connection: b'SBReceiver-e2a26b20-7d9b-47b9-bb70-da836bbcc74a'
2020-02-18 04:32:29,246 - ThreadPoolExecutor-0_2 -receiver - on_state_changed - uamqp.receiver - INFO - Message receiver b'receiver-link-05cabf7d-fd64-4f65-86c0-d5ce4c67b733' state changed from <MessageReceiverState.Open: 2> to <MessageReceiverState.Error: 4> on connection: b'SBReceiver-e2a26b20-7d9b-47b9-bb70-da836bbcc74a'
2020-02-18 04:32:29,246 - ThreadPoolExecutor-0_2 -connection - _state_changed - uamqp.connection - INFO - Connection b'SBReceiver-e2a26b20-7d9b-47b9-bb70-da836bbcc74a' state changed from <ConnectionState.OPENED: 9> to <ConnectionState.CLOSE_RCVD: 10>
2020-02-18 04:32:29,264 - ThreadPoolExecutor-0_2 -connection - _state_changed - uamqp.connection - INFO - Connection b'SBReceiver-e2a26b20-7d9b-47b9-bb70-da836bbcc74a' state changed from <ConnectionState.CLOSE_RCVD: 10> to <ConnectionState.END: 13>
2020-02-18 04:32:29,265 - ThreadPoolExecutor-0_2 -connection - _close_received - uamqp.connection - INFO - Received Connection close event: b'amqp:connection:forced'
Connection: b'SBReceiver-e2a26b20-7d9b-47b9-bb70-da836bbcc74a'
Description: b"The connection was inactive for more than the allowed 240000 milliseconds and is closed by container '2a83654461174e5492f21ff69047ec8d_G15'."
```

After this error the cpu max out.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are hitting 100% CPU with a single core, it is likely that the renew lock thread isn't getting time before the lock expires.

You should probably try increasing the number of cores in your VM depending on how compute intensive the processing is and also run the compute intensive process on a separate core by using the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) package.

[Here is a blog](https://medium.com/@urban_institute/using-multiprocessing-to-make-python-code-faster-23ea5ef996ba) that covers multi-core processing in python in good detail.

Also, since you seem to be trying to run at a minimal cost, [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview) is something you can consider using. If you require more than 10 minutes (max for consumption tier) per execution, you could consider using [Premium Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan).

Comment: Not looking at azure function as some files may take more than 5 minutes. Also even with multi core I see this issue of message lock acquired, where the other processor is just 5% used.

Comment: For the 5 minutes limitation, you could consider using Premium Functions. And for multi-core processing, I believe you will have to use the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) package. Here is a [blog](https://medium.com/@urban_institute/using-multiprocessing-to-make-python-code-faster-23ea5ef996ba) that covers this in good detail. Will update my answer with these as well.